# clipping model gradients by value for all layers in tf

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to clip by value all gradients in tensorflow1(to prevent really high or really low values, so not worried about directionaloty).
If I do this in a loop will this only be activated in graph construction or also graph activation?
code is below

```
grads_pre_clipping = optimizer.compute_gradients(total_loss, var_list=var_list)
grads =  [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, clip_values[var.name]["min"], clip_values[var.name]["max"]), var)
                                       for grad, var in grads_pre_clipping]
```

Its hard for me to tell if clipping is actually happening with this code

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. If you want to verify that clipping is happening during execution, you could print the values of gradients before and after clipping.

```
grads_pre_clipping = optimizer.compute_gradients(total_loss, var_list=var_list)
grads = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, clip_values[var.name]["min"], clip_values[var.name]["max"]), var)
         for grad, var in grads_pre_clipping]

# Print gradients
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Assuming you have initialized variables and defined the optimizer
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    gradients_values = sess.run([grad[0] for grad in grads], feed_dict={...})
    print(gradients_values)
```

This will show you the clipped gradient values during execution. If the gradients are within the specified range, the clipping is working as expected.